# Wordpress foreach invalid argument

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, jquery-isotope

Hoping someone can help me with this code. This code outputs the tax as a class for my isotope filte/items. It works fine on localhost but once uploaded it still works but creates the following error:

*Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /path-to-file.php on line #
*

```
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
  $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "print_type" );  //Get terms for item
  $termsString = ""; //initialize string that will contain the terms
    foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term 
    $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs 
    }
?> 
   <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?>"> 
   </div> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: use get_the_ID() instead of $post->ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /path-to-file.php on line # *

This warning is given when you feed a foreach loop with data that is not an array neither an object. Just adding an if condition to check for the same would work fine.

```
<?php
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ):
    $the_query->the_post(); 
    $termsArray  = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), "print_type" );  //Get terms for item
    $termsString = ""; //initialize string that will contain the terms

    // Only use foreach for a array or object.
    if( is_array($termsArray) ){
        foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term 
            $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs 
        }
    }
?>

<div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?>">
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: This creates an error further down the page at the endwhile statement. 
<?php
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post(); 
    $termsArray  = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "print_type" );  
    $termsString = ""; 
    if( is_array($termsArray) ){
        foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) {
            $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; 
        }
    }
}
?>
  <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?>">
  </div> 
<?php endwhile;  ?> <!-- here -->

Comment: And any idea why this would work on localhost (MAMP Pro) but not on server?

Comment: I updated the code to use : and endwhile notation for while loop. I normally use brackets.

Please debug your code on server to check the value of `$termsArray` you are getting. It most likely is false or null. If so then you need to check why it is so. I cannot say for sure but this might be due to difference databases on server on your local setup.

Comment: Also as @mouner-mostafa pointed out you need to use `get_the_ID()` as `$post` is not defined.

Comment: That worked - thx @Shivam Mathur. Have voted your answer up but not sure that I have enough reputation :(

Comment: Cool.
You can mark the answer as accepted. Here's how you do that.
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is your `$post->ID` it's undifiend .try this one

```
<?php 
     $guide = array(
        'post_type' => 'post', //type post type name here
        'posts_per_page' => -1, //number of posts
        );
query_posts($guide); while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php 
    $cats = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(),'type_terms_name_here');
    if($cats){
     foreach ($cats as $value){
         echo $value->term_id; //call term id
         echo $value->name; //call term name
         echo $value->slug; //call term slug
         echo $value->term_group; //call term_group
         echo $value->term_taxonomy_id; //call term_taxonomy_id
         echo $value->taxonomy; //call term taxonomy type
         echo $value->description; //call term description
         echo $value->count; // call term post count
     }
    }
    ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Can get this to work either @Mourner Can't get that to work either - it's not outputting the value  
`<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
  $cats = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), "print_type" ); 
  if($cats) {
    foreach ($cats as $value);
  }
  ?>
  <div class="<?php echo $value->name; ?>">`

Comment: are u calling terms name from specific post type ??? and what page did you use to display my answer ???